Is solving problems in this way low-level and should be avoided?
Introduction
Recently I have been reading the book "Thinking Mathematically" by John Mason at al.
I demonstrated using the method from the book to solve problems to a friend. He thought the process is what some immature student who cannot perform abstract thinking would do, like I am in elementary school. He said I should think about theorems and definitions and try to brings all the conditions together with them.
But I've solved so many problems by applying the methods described in the book. Previously I would just give up trying and ended up in failure on those problems.
An successful example of problem solving by thinking concretely
The problem
For example, suppose knowing for $a \le x \le b$,

$0 \le f(x) \le \pi$
$f'(x) \ge m > 0$

Prove
$$\left|\int_{a}^{b}\sin f(x) dx\right| \le {2 \over m}$$
The process
(Specialization)
Following the advices from the book, I should do specialization first. I interpret this as trying some functions that satisfy the constraints. Specializing $f'(x)$ to make it always equal to $m$, $f'(x)=m$, solving for $f(x)$, I got $f(x)= mx + c$, with a (further specialization) $m=1, a=0, b=\pi$, $f(x)$ then equals to $x$, the problem reduces to proving
$$\left|\int_0^\pi \sin x dx\right| \le 2$$
which is $|2| \le 2$, what? What does this specialization give me?
(Generalization) $a$ and $b$ could be any values, like $a=0, b = 1000000000$, this inequalities could still hold. But the function is strictly increasing! (Conjucturing) This means $m$ is inversely proportional to $b-a$. Another interesting finding is when $a=0 \le f(x) \le b=\pi$, $m$ cannot got larger than $1$. Maybe this indicates that $1 \over b-a$ would give an upper bound for $m$. If I rewrite the integral as
$$\left|\int_{a}^{b}\sin f(x) dx\right|=(b-a)\left|\sin f(\xi)\right| \le b-a, \xi \in (a,b)$$
(AHA moment) till here i suddenly got another idea to generalize the function to make it work for any $a$ and $b$
$$f(x)={x - a \over b - a}\pi={\pi \over b - a}x - {a\pi \over b - a}$$
so $m={\pi \over b - a}$ in this specific case, which provided further evidence for the earlier assumption that m is inverseily propertional to $b-a$. However, this doesn't provide any insight of how to prove the inequality, like, what does
$$\left|\int_a^b\sin {x - a \over b - a}\pi dx\right| \le {2\pi \over b - a}$$
even mean? Huh... since whatever inside $\sin$ is always 0 to $\pi$ and increasingly grows from $0$ to $\pi$, (AHA moment) maybe a substituion will bring some hope:
$$u={x - a \over b - a}\pi$$
wait ... then $du = mdx$! I just introduced $m$ one the left side, which might be a good sign!
$$\left|\int_a^b\sin {x - a \over b - a}\pi dx\right|={1 \over m}\left|\int_0^\pi \sin u du\right| = {2 \over m}$$
and because of symmetry, the integral
$${1 \over m}\left|\int_0^\pi \sin u du\right|={2 \over m}\left|\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \sin u du\right|$$
see! magically $2$ also popped out!
The final solution
The above process gives me inspiration to substitute $f(x)$
$$u=f(x), du = f'(x)dx, dx={1 \over f'(x)}du \le {1 \over m} du$$
Applying the substation (as well as symmetry) the inequality is proved:
$$\left|\int_a^b\sin f(x) dx\right|\le{2 \over m}\left|\int_0^{\pi\over 2}\sin u du\right| = {2 \over m}$$
My questions

Will this type of thinking take more time than abstract thinking?

Because my feeling is that though I can solve harder problems on which previously I cannot make any meaningful progress, but it did take more time. I think I solved problems in 20 minutes , though I learnt much more from the problem than I could before.

How an abstract thinker like my friend would approach this problem?

Should I avoid this low-level (as my friend thought) thinking and try to think abstractly?


I'm not willing to give up it though, since it just feels like that it suits me. It suits the way my brain works.

You should do what works for you. Everyone is different. There is no one-size-fits-all approach to problem solving.

This is a soft-question with a very soft-answer.
You are trying to work out some Exercise. You are stuck. There is no way to make Progress.
You think you have two "Options" :

(1) Either Quit that Exercise
(2) or use the Suggestions given in that text by Mason et al.

When you have more Options , it would make sense to worry whether (2) is good or (3) is better. Without those , it is a no-brainer that (2) is better than (1) : Quitting will not lead to learning !
Hence , without further thinking , I can safely say that you should continue what you are doing , without worrying about what your friend said.
Let us then check further whether that text is useful or not , more generally.
The reviews on Amazon are highly "Positive" from world-wide students / users / teachers / educators.
It is not some run-of-the-mill text , taken with more than 40 years of usage.
So that gives second confirmation that the text is good-to-use.
Let us consider the thinking behind such a text :
It lists Problem-Solving Heuristics which can work in a wide range of areas , mathematical or logical or beyond.
When somebody like your friend can go from Problem to Solution in a Straight-line , such methods might seem immature.

Those readers should not use this text.
There are a large number of thinkers who go in various Directions , to reach dead-ends & have to retry in other Directions. It will take multiple attempts to reach the Destination.

Definitely , those thinkers are the target audience for this text , where it will aid in "Identifying" various Directions to try.
That still confirms that the text is good.
Lastly , I would like to recommend this alternative text , which high-lights that the thinking behind the text is solid.
George Polya : "How to Solve it" is very similar , though much more well-known.
Polya is a genius. When the Heuristic Suggestions come from such a genius , I would listen to it.
Similar thinking listed in that text by Mason et al is then valid , not-with-standing what your friend said.
ADDENDUM :
Answering the updated questions which OP is asking.

Will this type of thinking take more time than abstract thinking?

In your Experience , it is taking less time. When you give up , you are taking infinite time. When you use this , you take up minutes or hours. Naturally , you should use it , until you have some alternative.

How an abstract thinker like my friend would approach this problem?

Your friend should answer it. Ask you friend some new Exercise & try to see the thinking used & check whether you can learn that way too.
Everybody will have a list of tricks to use.

Should I avoid this low-level (as my friend thought) thinking and try to think abstractly?

(3A) Not yet. You should first learn what that abstract thinking is & whether it suits use. You should ask you friend for references & learn that a little more. You can then take a call later.
(3B) Why not try both ? When this does not work , that might work ! You get the best of both worlds.
(3C) There might be better methods out there. Over time , you will learn more. Do not quit early , taking the negativity.

Thanks for your reasoning. I've read G. Polya's book but found it less helpful. Partly because the organization of the book is too loose, and too complicated, as well as that it is question-based, and I find myself usually cannot ask meaningful questions unless I've done something.

For 2). My friend, he is not a good explainer. One day he said he got some useful tricks from watching videos of a teacher. Then I asked him to point out one of such tricks in those videos, so I can understand what he is talking about. But he cannot point out any. So I don't think he is able to explain his thought process clearly.

When that is the Case , why would you want to emulate that ? It sounds like your friend wants to sound superior to you , hence the usage of words like immature & elementary school. I guess that when you two attempt some set of new questions , then you will end with more answers.

Thanks for your appreciation. I wanted to explore other possibilities, not to find supports for that I'm not inferior to my friend. It fascinates me that the problem could be solved in a completely different way without concrete understanding. So it's not about emulating my friend's abstract thinking, it about finding the "perfect version" of it that will like, completely blow my mind ...

The question title changed from 'Is solving problems in this way stupid and immature?" to "Is solving problems in this way low-level and should be avoided?" & it looks like that title might change again , because it looks like you are actually asking something else ! There are "Dozens" of ways to solve the Exercise you gave. When end result is good & valid , there is nothing to worry about here.
